# Setting @Value annotation with default variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Is it possible to use @Value annotation with a variable as default?

I have a variable `processingYear` , I would like to read from properties, If it cannot read from properties, I would like to assign the current year into the variable.

```
@Value("${processing_year:2021}")
int processingYear;
```

With the code specific above, I can read the `processingYear` from the properties file, and assign value to it, if reading from properties failed, the variable will be set to 2021.

However, I do not see a way to assign the current year as a default variable `currentYear`. Following is what I imagined and would like to see if there is anything to assign a default variable to it.

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    Locale locale = Locale.US;

    int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy",locale)));

    @Value("${process_year:currentYear}")
    int processingYear;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it with `@Value`

Just try this:

```java
@Value("${currentYear:#{(T(java.time.Year).now().getValue())}}")
private int year;
```

Comment: How about if I want to set ```private String month;``` to "Feb" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can provide as below :

```java
@Value("${processing_year:5}")
int processingYear;
```

Provide the default value after `:`. This would assign a default value of `5` to `processingYear`

If you want to provide other values then you need to prefix with `#`:

```java
@Value("$someObj.value:#{null}}")
Object someObj;

@Value("#{'${someObject.stringlist:}'.split(',')}")
Collection<String> strings;
```

If you need to set a variable, then you need to use `@Value` along with a setter method:

```java
int processingYear;

@Value("${process_year:-1}")
private void setProcessingYear(int year) {
    if(year == -1) {
        // -1 used to identify that no value was passed. so in this case we use currentyear.
        year = currentyear;
    }
    processingYear = year;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gautham, I have tried, but with the following error message ```Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'currentYear' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?```

Comment: field ```currentYear``` is already public, and both ```currentYear``` and ```processingYear``` are global variables.

Comment: @PoonJP I have updated my answer. In your case, you need to use a setter method and `@Value`

Comment: Thanks. I have something like that before, but I would like to see if there is anything I can simplify using the @value annotation.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to do that directly with the field. Using a setter might be the best option as you could easily debug to analyze any issues

Comment: My program was implemented about 10 years ago, so I have already implemented my own properties reader with default value. As I am in the progress of revamping the program with spring-boot, I would just like to see if I am able to ditch the self-implemented properties reader with @value annotation.

Comment: Yes but using a setter won't make much of a difference right? Also, if you want to set a value from another variable in the class then you either need to use `@Value` with constructor or a setter. I would suggest a setter method because it keeps the code simpler than with a constructor and we are using the setter approach in our team as well.